# How to call a stored procedure inside the other stored procedure

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005, also I create another stored proc (that accepts some input parameters), I have to invoke with the use of the first proc.

Comment: These are called store*D" procedures - **STORED** as in stored in SQL Server - **NOT** "store" procedures....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_inner (@value INT)
AS
        SELECT  @value
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_outer (@value INT)
AS
        EXEC prc_inner @value
GO

EXEC prc_outer 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up [EXEC sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx) or just plain EXEC [storedprocedurename]

Comment: How to define the parameter that i have to pass the proc.?

Comment: See Quassnoi's answer for that :)